# How to transmit data from one page to another one when they are connected through a link?

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image]I have a database, and a page called Teacher's_request_display.php which shows data from it (you can see an image of it below).
What I want to do is to click on a random row (specifically on the description part, which is the biggest cell), so that it will transfer me to another page, Teacher's_request_detailed.php This page should show me information about this job, info that can't be seen in Teacher's_request_display.php, which means that it has to be connected to the database.

What should I do so that Teacher's_request_detailed.php can receive the correct data (the clicked one)? I can add an "ID" column to my table in phpmyadmin so that the requests could be differentiated, but how should Teacher's_request_detailed.php detect it and connect to the right row in the db?

I am attaching Teacher's_request_display.php below. Teacher's_request_detailed.php is not important, it's just supposed to show info.

```
<?php
  include_once 'Connection.php';
?>


 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Display</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "Display_style.css">
</head>



<body>
    <script src = "Myscript.js"></script>
    <h1 style = "text-align: center;">Существующие работы   </h1>
    <p style = "text-align: left;">Сортировка</p> 
    <button onclick = "SortByPayment()">Оплата</button>
    <button onclick = "SortByPeople()">Люди</button>
    <button onclick = "SortByUrgency()">Срочность</button>
    <button onclick = "SortByDifficulty()">Сложность</button>
        <br> <br> <br>
<table style = "width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th style = "width:13%">Работодатель</th>   
        <th>Описание работы</th>
        <th style = "width:8%">Оплата</th>
        <th style = "width:8%">Количество людей</th>
        <th style = "width:10%">Срочность</th>
        <th style = "width:8%">Сложность</th>       
    </tr>
</table>


<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM trequests;";
  $conn = Connect();
  mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8');
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  //<td style = "width:13%">'.$row['ID'].'</td>
  $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);  
  echo '<table style = "width:100%"; id = "All_Trequests">';
  if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "  <tr>
                  <td style = \"width:13%\">".$row['Customer']."</td>
                  <td class = \"job-style\" title = \"".$row['The_Job']."\"
                  onclick = \"location.href = 'Teacher's_request_detailed.php'\">
                  <a href = \"Teacher's_request_detailed.php\">"
                  .$row['The_Job']."</a></td>
                  <td style = \"width:8%\">".$row['Paymentfro']."-".$row['Paymentto']."</td>
                  <td style = \"width:8%\">".$row['Amount']."</td>
                  <td style = \"width:10%\">".$row['Urgency']."</td>
                  <td style = \"width:8%\">".$row['Difficulty']."</td>      
                </tr>";

    }
  echo '</table>';  
  }

?>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You may wanna look into `POST` and `GET` parameter. Especially `$_GET` would do that you're looking for.

Comment: You can add parameters to the URL: `example.com/something?foo=bar&something=foobar`